# vb.net divistion wrong outcome

Tags: vb.net

A very weird issue happens when substracting two numbers in vb.net
It returns a wrongful outcome for a very simple math equation :
I am using visual studio 2019
I don't want to use any math.round to fix the value for such simple equation
Any ideas why that issue happens?

```vb
Dim diff As Decimal = 100.1 - 100
MsgBox(diff)
```

it returns 0.0999999999999943

[image: MsgBox(diff)]

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: Not a duplicate of that question, but that question's accepted answer generally explains what the issue is. But it doesn't really provide a solution.

Comment: Before you continue on with anymore software development, you should read [this article](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html), which will explain everything you ever need to know about floating point numbers and computers.

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot more going on in your math than you assume! You have three different primitive types there:

- 100.1 is a Double
- 100 is an Integer
- diff is a Decimal

If you put `Option Strict On` at the top of your code, your code will not compile. This will tell you

> Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Double' to 'Decimal'.

So you must either explicitly cast (this is what your `Option Strict Off` version is doing implicitly)

```
Dim diff As Decimal = CDec(100.1 - 100)
```

but since it's the same thing you are already doing implicitly, you will get that same floating point issue. The better thing to do is to start with a Decimal instead of Double in the first place, such as

```
Dim diff = 100.1D - 100
```

By using the Decimal literal `D` at the end of the floating point number it actually does Decimal math, and the result:

[image]

Comment: thanks djv , 
works like magic 
here is my final code :
                    DBG1.Rows(row).Cells(8).Value = CDec(Val(DBG1.Rows(row).Cells(6).Value)) - (CDec(Val(DBG1.Rows(row).Cells(5).Value)) * CDec(Val(DBG1.Rows(row).Cells(4).Value)))

Comment: @MouhammadAbbasi that doesn't look right. You've got to stop using outdated functions such as `MsgBox` and `Val`, instead use `MessageBox.Show` and the appropriate numeric parsing / casting functions. Based on your comment, you may still have an issue with floating point conversions. Your question should include that code.

Comment: noted , thanks alot

Comment: @MouhammadAbbasi Use this instead: `Decimal.Parse(DBG1.Rows(row).Cells(6).Value)` to parse the string directly into decimal, then you won't lose precision when converting first to Double with `Val` then Decimal with `CDec`